# Optimise Show/Hide multiple divs from different sources

Tags: jquery, optimization, onclick, toggle

I am trying to have four buttons (called blurbs on Divi Builder), that when I click on either one, it will show a specific section (div) and hide the other three sections, so that only one is ever displayed at a time.

This is what I currently have:

```
<!--Photographer script-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#bphotographer").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sclient").hide();
        jQuery("#sshoot").hide();
        jQuery("#sproduct").hide();        
    });
    jQuery("#bphotographer").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sphotographer").show();
    });
});
</script>

<!--Client script-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#bclient").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sphotographer").hide();
        jQuery("#sshoot").hide();
        jQuery("#sproduct").hide();        
    });
    jQuery("#bclient").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sclient").show();
    });
});
</script>

<!--Shoot script-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#bshoot").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sphotographer").hide();
        jQuery("#sclient").hide();
        jQuery("#sproduct").hide();        
    });
    jQuery("#bshoot").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sshoot").show();
    });
});
</script>

<!--Product script-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#bproduct").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sphotographer").hide();
        jQuery("#sclient").hide();
        jQuery("#sshoot").hide();        
    });
    jQuery("#bproduct").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sproduct").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

It's not very optimised but it works and no errors appear in the Inspect panel on Chrome.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to optimise it?

Thank you,

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want do show and hide only one div you can add a attribute in your menu click event with the same name of your divs id and add one same class for all div for hide each in same time.

Please try below:

```js
$(".menu").click(function(){
  $(".tab").hide();
  $("#"+ $(this).attr("data-div") ).show();
});
```

```css
.menu{
  cursor:pointer;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bphotographer" class="menu" data-div="sphotographer">bphotographer</div>
<div id="bshoot" class="menu" data-div="sshoot">bshoot</div>
<div id="bclient" class="menu" data-div="sclient">bclient</div>
<div id="bproduct" class="menu" data-div="sproduct">bproduct</div>


<div id="sphotographer" class="tab" style="display:none;height:100px;height:100px;background:blue"></div>
<div id="sshoot" class="tab" style="display:none;height:100px;height:100px;background:red"></div>
<div id="sclient" class="tab" style="display:none;height:100px;height:100px;background:yellow"></div>
<div id="sproduct" class="tab" style="display:none;height:100px;height:100px;background:green"></div>
```

Comment: Well it's taken me a while to get it working. I am using a web page builder which made it difficult to implement your code (the data-div part), but I finally got around it. Your code was brilliant! Thank you so much, I've learned how to implement an onclick feature :)